# Getting $ in response for Date field from API, is this a valid response?

Tags: android, json, mongodb, response

Getting `$` in response for some fields generated from mongo db, can't parse them as in kotlin `$` is value of the key:

```
"arrival_dt": {
    "**$date**": 1520726400000
},
"_id": {
    "**$oid**": "5c2600cf234e1b0ca8f03944"
}
```

How can we remove this `$` from response generated from mongo db?

Comment: Improved formatting.

Comment: Can't you just specify the JSON name of the field in Kotlin?